# How to change Toolbar and MessageBox language in Crystal report viewer in C#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

How to change Toolbar and MessageBox language in Crystal report viewer? Example in zoom "Page Width" and "Whole Page", and Message Box "Please wait while the document is processing" and "Export Completed". also Tooltips.
Shortly, i need to change Crystal report viewer language, not in Pages but Controls.

Comment: You may get a better response to this type of question from the SAP support website.

Comment: Ok. thank you R. McMillan..